# jQuery stop animation and start new animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a function which animates a div from the bottom of the page to display a system message

```
function showSystemMessage(iMessage, iType)
{   
    $(".systemMessage").removeClass("success error");
    $(".systemMessage").animate({ bottom: "0px" }, 600);
    $(".systemMessage").html(iMessage).addClass(iType);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".systemMessage").animate({ bottom: "-40px" }, 600);
    }, 3000);
}
```

It is called like this

```
showSystemMessage("Thanks for voting", "success");
```

or this

```
showSystemMessage("An error occured", "error");
```

The function works fine but the problem is that when I call it twice the animation will just finish the first time.

What I want it that when I call the function it should animate the `.systemMessage` div and when I call it again immediately after the first time it should stop the first animation and begin the second one so that I see both message.

I tried something like `.stop()` but I don´t know how to deal with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implementation with .stop()

```
function showSystemMessage(iMessage, iType)
{   
    $(".systemMessage").removeClass("success error");
    $(".systemMessage").stop().animate({ bottom: "0px" }, 600);
    $(".systemMessage").html(iMessage).addClass(iType);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".systemMessage").stop().animate({ bottom: "-40px" }, 600);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Before starting a new animation, you have to stop() current animations. So add .stop() before .animate()

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I figured out that the main problem is the setTimeout function. After 3 seconds the div will be animated back where it was before. So I have to clear the timeout somehow before animating I suppose?